# Testing a desktop application

Tags: testing, nunit, desktop-application

I need to open a .exe application where I have to test all the functions, UI, etc.
I were working with watin and Nunit for testing a web, but now, i think watin is useless for this. I found NunitForms, but I dont think that will be enough.

I have to open the application and test all the windows, buttons, etc that appear. The application also start minimized in the taskbar and have a desplegable menu.

How can I handle it? Thanks!

Comment: This question might be more suitable for [sqa.stackexchange.com](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to Winforms application. Please check below links

The Microsoft UI Automation Library - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/site/cc163288

UI Automation with Windows PowerShell - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/site/cc163301

Lightweight UI Test Automation with .NET - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/site/cc163864

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you want as little code in the forms as possible.  If you move the functionality to separate classes, those can easily be tested using NUnit.  If you must test the forms directly, NUnitForms is a reasonable tool.